# Voltage and current rating of electrical systems

Tags: current, electric-machine, rms, ratings

Why voltage and current ratings of almost all electrical systems are RMS value of voltage and current not peak value of voltage and current?

First I thought maybe because mostly ac input is sinusoidal and for sinusoids rms and peak values are directly related so it doesn't matter whether rating is in rms or peak

But sometimes even a sinusoidal  input voltage can cause a non sinusoidal current or even if we take worst case scenario where both input and output are non sinusoidal where no direct relationship exist between peak and RMS values and hence RMS value cannot determine peak value in these cases

So ,why RMS rating is considered ?

isn't insulation failure (and many other failure) occur  at peak of current and voltages rather than RMS of these quantities? For example even  a low RMS currents and voltages can have very  high value of peak which might damage the device.

Comment: "isn't insulation failure (and many other failure) occur at peak of current and voltages rather than RMS of these quantities?" Tested insulation values should always be higher than both peak and RMS value, so this is not a problem. Industrial standards have this covered.

Comment: Also, maximum currents are RMS currents, not peak, as it's the thermal heating that determines them in almost all cases. In fact, it's usually an average over many minutes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why voltage and current ratings of almost all electrical systems are RMS value of voltage and current not peak value of voltage and current?

The main reason is for power calculations. The V<sub>RMS</sub> value is that value which will give the same heating effect as the same numerical value in DC. This then means that we can use the standard formulas \$ V = IR \$, \$ P = I^2R \$ and \$ P = \frac {V^2} R \$ in our calculations.

[image]

A typical dimmer waveform. The relationship between phase angle delay and resultant RMS voltage is graphed on the right. Image source: [Dimmers for LEDs](http://lednique.com/bulbs/dimmers-for-leds/).*

Remember that the RMS value will work with non-sinusoidal waveforms too whereas the peak voltage will tell you nothing.

> First I thought maybe because mostly ac input is sinusoidal and for sinusoids rms and peak values are directly related so it doesn't matter whether rating is in rms or peak.

I think I've covered that.

> But sometimes even a sinusoidal input voltage can cause a non sinusoidal current or even if we take worst case scenario where both input and output are non sinusoidal where no direct relationship exist between peak and RMS values and hence RMS value cannot determine peak value in these cases.

Devices using rectifiers usually generate non-sinusoidal current waveforms. Think about a mains or transformer supply charging a capacitor through a rectifier: no current will flow until the supply voltage exceeds the capacitor voltage so the current waveform will appear as a pulse when *V* is close to maximum.

If you want to calculate power then you need to average the product of the voltage and current over time.

> So ,why RMS rating is considered ?

For the mathematics.

> Isn't insulation failure (and many other failure) occur at peak of current and voltages rather than RMS of these quantities? For example even a low RMS currents and voltages can have very high value of peak which might damage the device.

Yes, so the crest factor (ratio between peak and RMS values) will have to be considered in any design.

Comment: Thanks for answer ! a doubt in last paragraph as you mentioned that crest factor Will have to consider ,but in transformer only voltage and KVA rating is given so why in books author  neglect Crest factor in case of transformer ?

Comment: See if http://blog.powerandtest.com/blog/what-is-crest-factor-and-why-is-it-important answers this a bit. The crest-factor problem is one for the user, not the transformer manufacturer.

Answer (score 8):

Because, historically, AC systems competed with DC systems to supply power.

Now to supply the same power as a 100V DC system, the AC system must provide 100V RMS.

RMS measurement was thus a way to keep the utilities honest, in the days when both were in competition, and the underlying reason (its relation to power delivery) ensures it is still the standard for measurement today.

Answer (score 3):

If you're designing any appliance with a heating element (and that includes tungsten filament lamps), then it's the power that really matters.  Too little power, and the appliance won't do its job.  Too much power, and the appliance burns out.

There is an equation for the power:

> P = V² / R

So if you know the power you want, and the supply voltage, then you can calculate the resistance you need.

For DC supplies, the voltage is obvious.  If you work through the maths, it turns out that for an AC supply, you need to use the RMS voltage.  The peak voltage doesn't work, as most of the time, the voltage is below the peak.